# NSPredicateEditor row templates not configurable in interface builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nspredicateeditor

I'm creating an assistant sheet in my storyboard in interface builder. The viewController contains an `NSPredicateEditor` and is connected to a property of the viewController using cocoa bindings.

However, I'm not able to properly configure the row templates. When I uncheck one of the predicate operators, I'm not able to re-enable them, nor I'm able to use any of the other provided operators.

[image: GIF illustrating the issue]

Doesn't Xcode support `NSPredicateEditor` anymore, or am I doing anything wrong here? Just to be clear, I'm not having any code jet.

Comment: I tried this and had to force quit Xcode. Close and open the project and try to modify the row template before doing anything else.

Comment: Wow – Xcodes bugginess again... Thanks a lot for the sharp eye! Please add an answer, so you can get the rep ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode. I tried this with and without storyboards and had to force quit Xcode in both cases while configuring the binding. Close and open the project and try to modify the row template before doing anything else.