# NSWindows controls check boxes in Interface Builder in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm using IB to design a Cocoa application.

I have created two storyboards and each one has an instance of `NSWindowController`.

In one of them, I unchecked accidentally the *resize* checkbox of the `NSWindow` and I am unable to check it again. A small "-" appears and disappears just after.

[image: appearing of the minus]
[image: disappearing of the minus]

Is it a bug in Interface Builder ?

Comment: Similar problem: [NSPredicateEditor row templates not configurable in interface builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321303/nspredicateeditor-row-templates-not-configurable-in-interface-builder/40329011#40329011)