# XCode (8.2 (8C38)) bug? Cocoa Application: Window Attributes Inspector: Resize, Close, Minimize can't be checked

Tags: xcode, cocoa, attributes, resize

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new Cocoa Application, use Storyboards.
2. Click on the Window (in the Window Controller), go to the Attributes Inspector, and try toggling Resize, Close, and Minimize. Works fine.
3. Now drag the default created ViewController to a new position in the storyboard window. Drag it anywhere, doesn't matter.
4. Now try to toggle the properties listed in step 2. They can no longer be enabled.

Is this correct? A bug? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I tried in Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) and see similar behavior. Looks like a bug. If you quit Xcode and open project again, you apparently get those options again. I'd suggest posting a bug report http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Bug submitted.

Comment: Duplicate of [NSWindows controls check boxes in Interface Builder in Xcode 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242431/nswindows-controls-check-boxes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8)